# How to create a Seaborn Pairplot legend

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

This is my code for plotting some covid data for California and Texas. I have simply just taken my big dataframe (`df_covidNew`) and only looking at CA and TX.

```
df_CA = df_covidNew[df_covidNew.state == "CA"]
df_TX = df_covidNew[df_covidNew.state == "TX"]
```

I then used a `groupby()` function to get the information that I want to plot in a pairplot:

```
CA = df_CA.groupby(['month','month_name','state'])[['positive','negative','hospitalizedCurrently','death']].sum()
TX = df_TX.groupby(['month','month_name','state'])[['positive','negative','hospitalizedCurrently','death']].sum()
```

I then used `concat` to merge the two DataFrames together:

```
df = pd.concat([CA,TX])
```

Using seaborn I tried to plot it, but it comes out as the same colour. There is no differentiation between CA and TX, which makes the plot pretty much useless.

```
sns.pairplot(df)
```

This is what it looks like:
[PairPlot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBaP8.png)

Is there a way I am able to differentiate between TX and CA in terms of a legend? I tried the legend method but it just says 'no legend handles'.

Comment: Based on the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html), how about `sns.pairplot(df, hue="state")`?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler that didn't work. It just came back with, key error.

Comment: @Timble Weird - I'd expect that to work. Can you post the output of `print(df.columns)` ?

Comment: @NickODell output: Index(['positive', 'negative', 'hospitalizedCurrently', 'death'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the seaborn [pairplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) and structure of your DataFrame, I think you need to reset your MultiIndex into columns, then pass `hue="state"`:

```
sns.pairplot(df.reset_index(), hue="state")
```